# I am now ready to publish my commercial Android/IPhone/Anything application - what disclaimers should I use to protect myself?

Tags: licensing

I have now written my last line of code and I am ready to publish my application to the Android Market, what disclaimers should I add to protect myself as a developer from customers who purchase my application, to prevent being sued by stupid people?

It might be a harsh question, but how does developers protect themselves when publishing their software? Developers or small companies (for example all these iPhone/Android developers) that can't afford hiring a small army of lawyers, what should they do?

Any solid text I can use?

Comment: This might be a harsh question, but when you looked at other Android apps, what did you see?  Please summarize what you've already read from apps similar to yours.

Comment: I haven't seen any disclaimers from others. I don't think the typical Android developer adds a disclaimer.

Comment: @corgrath: That answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: No, because I actually want one. Even though it won't be totally bulletproof unless I hire an army of lawyers, I still want to know the basic :-)

Comment: Are you selling the application or giving it away?

Comment: I am selling the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think something along the lines of "this software is provided as-is and comes with no warranties or guarantees. Do not use for real-time mission-critical systems, life-support systems etc... User assumes all responsibility by using this software... The author assumes no responsibility for loss of data, loss of limbs, loss of life, loss of livelihood, loss of soul, loss of hair, loss of libido..." should do.

Have a look at other disclaimers to see what they say, that's where I picked up these little bits and pieces.